# getting error on live server "Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null"

Tags: php

Sometimes live server throws that error.It working fine in localhost while giving this error in live server.It happens sometimes not everytime.anyone please tell me the reason and solution.

here is the code where i am getting error...

```
 $prices=array();
  $price1=$property_type['price1'];
  if (!empty($price1)) {
  array_push($prices, $price1);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **isset()**

```
$prices = array(); 

if(isset($property_type['price1'])) array_push($prices, $property_type['price1']);
```

Comment: still giving error....it giving error on that line " $price1=$property_type['price1']; "

Comment: thank u soo much...its fine now

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```
$prices=array();

if (isset($property_type['price1']) && $property_type['price1'] !== null) {

  $price1=$property_type['price1'];
  array_push($prices, $price1);

}
```

Comment: thank u soo much bro..its fine now

Answer (score 1):

You should not assign to $price1 without knowing whether $property_type['price1'] is empty or nonempty. First, you should query whether $property_type['price1'] is empty or nonempty.

you can code:

```
$prices=array();
if(!empty($property_type['price1'])){
 array_push($prices, $property_type['price1']);
}
```

Comment: thanx bro...i exactly did that...now its working fine

Answer (score 1):

This error could be triggered if `$property_type['price1']` is null or not set. Make sure it is set before trying to access it as an array element

```
$prices = array();
if (isset($property_type['price1'])) {
    $price1 = $property_type['price1'];
    if (!empty($price1)) {
        array_push($prices, $price1);
    }
}
```